# compare text lines(multiple lists) using python

Tags: python

I have the text file which contains below lines:

```
Cycle 0 DUT 2 Bad Block : 2,4,6,7,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28
Cycle 0 DUT 3 Bad Block : 4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26
Cycle 0 DUT 4 Bad Block : 4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26
Cycle 1 DUT 2 Bad Block : 2,4,6,7,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28
Cycle 1 DUT 3 Bad Block : 4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32
```

I want to compare the `Cycle 0 DUT 2` text line (numbers after colon separated with commas) to the `Cycle 1 DUT 2` text line (numbers after colon seperated with commas) and get the differences, then compare `Cycle 0 DUT 3` text line to `Cycle 1 DUT 3` text line and get the differences or the unique values.

Comment: OK, and what's your question? Which part of the problem do you need help with?

Comment: Also, you need to be more specific. Does the order of elements matter? Will there be more lines than those (for example a Cycle 2 etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to key things to to the `DUT` digit:

```
import re
dut_data = {}

cycle_dut = re.compile('^Cycle\s+(\d)\s+DUT\s+(\d)\s+Bad Block\s*:\s*(.*)$')

with open(inputfile, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        match = cycle_dut.search(line)
        if match:
            cycle, dut, data = match.groups()
            data = [int(v) for v in data.split(',')]
            if cycle == '0':
                # Store cycle 0 DUT values keyed on the DUT number
                dut_data[dut] = data
            else:
                # Compare against cycle 0 data, if the same DUT number was present
                cycle_0_data = dut_data.get(dut)
                if cycle_0_data is not None:
                    # compare cycle_0_data and data here
                    print 'DUT {} differences: {}'.format(dut, ','.join([str(v) for v in sorted(set(cycle_0_data).symmetric_difference(data))]))
```

I used a quick set difference to print the differences, this may require refining.

For your sample data, this prints:

```
DUT 2 differences: 
DUT 3 differences: 28,30,32
```